# Saving input data from a program without a database

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a simple task tracking WPF application and want to save the data entered by the user without the use of a full on Database.

Here is some sample data that I would like to save.

1. Date

   - Creation / completed
2. Task(Title/description)
3. Active of Inactive
4. Maybe Priority

I have been reading posts and some people are suggesting ini, CSV, app.config with XAML. I would just like to know what is a good standard choice for what I am looking to accomplish. Something that is solid so that my app can run with little to no setup from an end-user after its deployed.

Comment: Have you considered deserialization into xml?

Comment: CSV would be really helpful as it can be viewed as an Excel sheet and closely resembles a Table structure as well. [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) is a very popular library to manipluate CSV files

Comment: You can save  your data with serializing it to JSON or Xml and write it to the file with that format.

Comment: Keep CSV easy for you to import in Database if needed in future.

Comment: SQLite requires no user setup and is a very small dependency that will give you a true SQL database with all the attendant benefits.

Answer (score 1):

As an example, I'll use the following class as the top-tier database "object" you want to save:

```
[Serializable]
public class Model
{
    public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

AJAX is probably the most commonly used "simple" solution of your options, which means either JSON or XAML. JSON is more better suited to "data" whereas XML is better suited to "documents".

For JSON you do something like this:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer();

using (var stream = new StreamWriter("filename.dat"))
    serializer.Serialize(stream, model);

using (var stream = new StreamReader("filename.dat"))
using (var reader = new JsonTextReader(stream))
{
    var copy = serializer.Deserialize<Model>(reader);
}
```

Which produces a file like this:

```
{"Data":"Hello World!"}
```

For XAML you do something like this:

```
var model = new Model { Data = "Hello World!" };

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Model));
using (var stream = new StreamWriter("filename.dat"))
    serializer.Serialize(stream, model);

using (var stream = new StreamReader("filename.dat"))
{
    var copy = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Model;
}
```

Which produces a file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Model xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Data>Hello World!</Data>
</Model>
```

And of course if you're a sucker for punishment you can serialize into a .NET binary format directly:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

using (var stream = new FileStream("filename.dat", FileMode.Create))
    formatter.Serialize(stream, model);

using (var stream = new FileStream("filename.dat", FileMode.Open))
{
    var copy = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as Model;
}
```

Which will in turn create a file utterly useless for anything other than this.

All of these "solutions" unfortunately come with the caveat of needing to read and write the entire thing into memory every time you want to work with it, and to get around that you will have to use a database I'm afraid. But if you don't want to use a "full on" database then how about a "Lite" one? Specifically, SQLite? Advantages include:

- Data is all stored in a local file, in a location of your own choosing.
- It's completely self-contained, no need to install a database server on your target machines.
- Supported by virtually every platform under the sun (and they all use the same format).
- Integrates easily with ORMs like EntityFramework etc.
- There are tons of free 3rd-party utilities like LINQPad etc that allow you to open and work with the database file directly.

Coupling SQLite with something like EntityFramework is particularly handy, because the code to access and write to the database is extremely straightforward:

```
using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
{
    foreach (var model in db.Models)
        // do something with the model here
}
```

It also means that once your application makes a million dollars and you want to migrate to a "proper" DB engine you'll already have the ORM architecture in place. The main downside is that the initial setup for SQLite in particular is a little annoying, but you only have to do it once. Here are my own personal notes that I refer to for each project I use it on, enjoy!

Step 1 - Create a console or WPF application

Step 2 - Add Nuget package System.Data.SQLite

Step 3 - Add Nuget package SQLite.CodeFirst (this will also install Entity Framework as a dependency)

Step 4 - Add the models and DatabaseContext classes (plenty of references on the net showing how to do this for EF).

Step 5 - Adjust the App.config file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyDatabase" connectionString="data source=MyDatabase.db;foreign keys=True;password=password" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Step 6 - Add reference to System.Configuration so that code can read the config file.

Step 7 - Run the application, the database file will be created when you create the DatabaseContext object for the first time.

Comment: Ajax is a web technology used to update parts of a page. I don't see how that has anything to do with the question. I would think serialisation is the most commonly used for small pieces of data and a local database for large complicated data.

Comment: I'd certainly agree that they were originally designed for that, but I think it's also fair to say it's extended beyond that and is now used extensively in many other environments including mobile and desktop applications. That's been my observation, anyway.

Comment: BTW, thanks whoever it was that just up-voted me, you just gave me moderator privileges! :D

Comment: No, Thank you for the awesome reply. Such an informative post. I will look into JSON and SQLite.